# Errors in this repository

Tags: flutter, dart

I was taking a course which had old version of Flutter SDk which showed errors at main.dart files which I was able to eliminate by changing the dependencies in the .yaml file. *But* The file names color turned red when I did that change. Is it a problem or its just that way?

One other issue is again with the .yaml file where I cannot understand why it shows error when i use asset image from the folder. I followed exactly how the course instructed but the image is thrown everytime.
This is the code from the .yaml file

```yaml
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - Images/diamond.png
```

and this is the code from the main file.

```
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[900],
        title: const Center(child: Text('I am rich')),
      ),
      body: const Center(
        child: Image(image: AssetImage('Images/diamond.png')),
      ),
    ),
  ));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no error in your code.
However, If this still doesn't solve your problem you can check some possible causes.

1. Make sure you make an `Image` folder on your root directory(not inside the lib).
2. Check the spelling of your directory/file.
3. Double-check the indentation of pubspec yaml file.
4. run `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get`

Answer (score 0):

There is no error in this you are good to go. Just reset the dependencies and by running flutter clean and it will solve the issue

Comment: I have tried that but it doesnt work. the file and folders names are still red. Is that a problem tho?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see an error in your code. If you're still getting errors, clean it with flutter clean. Click get dependency in the .yaml file and run your code again.